# Can I varnish wooden worktops that have previously been oiled?

Tags: wood, kitchen-counters, protection

The previous owners of our house fitted wooden worktops in the kitchen. While these look nice, they need constant maintenance (re-oiling every three months) to stop water getting in - which we don't have the time to do to the standard I'd like, as it effectively means not using the kitchen for a week every time we do it (three sections of worktop, each needing multiple coats which, when working full time, we can only do one coat a day, especially in the colder weather when everything takes longer to dry).

Can I sand down the surface and varnish/lacquer it instead, in order to better protect it while reducing the maintenance liability? If so, what properties do I need to look for in the varnish?

Comment: I've revised your title to what I think is the key issue. You can certainly varnish countertops, so that's not the critical point. Edit again if you like.

Comment: @isherwood thanks, that is the issue - and how to find a varnish that's safe for kitchen use

Comment: From my perspective, safety is only a factor if you're regularly preparing food *directly on the top*. If that's the case, you'll wear through varnish and it'll end up in your food. Keep the oiled wood.

Comment: good point - no, we always use chopping boards for the food prep!

Comment: What kind of oil do you use--mineral oil, tung oil, or something else? Why does it take so long to oil it? Could you shorten the job by doing a lighter oiling (applying less oil at each re-oiling) which might dry overnight?

Comment: I apply Peanut Oil to the top of [this 800lb beast](https://i.imgur.com/xa590I2.jpg) about every 3 days.  It takes about 15 seconds.  Every month or two, I do the sides also, that takes 5 minutes.

Comment: This may be sacrilege to suggest, but have you considered laminate? Easy to clean, not really all that hard to install. I would also think that varnish (varathane, ureathane,) wouldn't wear as well as you think, they really aren't made for a "working surface".   If you decide to refinish, I'd look into some epoxy based finishes that could stand up to the rigors of a kitchen countertop.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson that's what we did in the end, replaced them with new laminate ones, which are much more practical for us.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply varnish on top of oil, but the oil should not be fresh / wet.  It might help to go over the surface with fine steel wool and mineral oil to prepare it.  You could consider Danish oil, which is a combination of varnish and oil.